# Save "state" of an Object in use, for further comparison (No Serialization)

Tags: java, object, compare, comparison, state

```
    GenericObject MyObj = new GenericObject();

    MyObjs.add(); // operation 1

    // operation for saving the current state of "MyObj"

    MyObjs.add(); // operation 2 (it is the same as 1, repeated)

    // Comparison with previous saved state of "MyObj" -> this will return **false**

    MyObjs.remove(); // operation 3 (this operation cancel the effect of operation 2)

    // Comparison with previous saved state of "MyObj" -> this will return **true**
```

I would save the "state" of an object, how variables are when I store its state in some way and after use it to compare the future states of the object.

With Serialization I could serialize everytime the Object and than deserialize and compare but I can't use serialization. How is it possible with standard libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jackson-JSON library to dump an object's state in json format without implementing Serialization interface in your class and again load the object by reading from that json data and mapping back to the object type.

Simply use ObjectMapper for this purpose.

Example:

```
//do some stuff here with your MyObj object

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonState1 = mapper.writeValueAsString(MyObj);

//do some stuff here

String jsonState2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(MyObj);
```

When you want to compare any of them, you can just do:

```
GenericObject objState1 = mapper.readValue(jsonState1, GenericObject.class);
```

Then do whatever comparison you want to do.

Hope that helps!!

**Update**:

> If you want to use standard Java library only, then you have no other
>   choice than using Java Reflection API. With this API you can access
>   the class variables and their getter and setter methods, in fact
>   everything a class holds. But unfortunately you need to write whole
>   bunch of codes to do that. But that's the only choice if you don't
>   want to use Java Serialization.

Comment: Your solution is good, but sorry I updated the question, I must use only Java standard library.